# org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint:

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, resttemplate

I'm new to Spring boot framework, recently i created a spring boot web application, if i run the application locally, it is working fine and gives me the desired output but when i tried to build, testcases are failing with the error:

> 1) org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint:
>
> 2)org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500

**Here is my code:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BootCamelApplication.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class BootCamelApplicationTest {
    @Test
    public void test(){
        final String requestBody = "payload";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestBody, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> result = null;
        try{
            result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

please tell me where i went wrong.